# About special characters in java

Tags: java, android, text, special-characters

In my application about World of Warcraft mythic dungeons i have to do some queries into the raiderio Public API. I having a big issue when the players name it's something like this :

```
https://raider.io/api/v1/characters/profile?region=US&realm=https://raider.io/characters/us/zuljin/Børomìr&name=&fields=mythic_plus_best_runs%3Aall

this name : Børomìr
```

In the API this query doesn't work because it manages special characters like this:

```
https://raider.io/api/v1/characters/profile?region=us&realm=zuljin&name=B%C3%B8rom%C3%ACr&fields=mythic_plus_best_runs%3Aall

becomes this : B%C3%B8rom%C3%ACr
```

where:

`ø` becomes `%C3%B8`

`ì` becomes `%C3%AC`

which tool do i need to generate this conversion in java?

Heres is the URL request code:

```
            String body = "";
            URL url = new URL("https://raider.io/api/v1/characters/profile?region="+region.toString()+"&realm="+realm+"&name="+name+"&fields=mythic_plus_best_runs%3Aall");
            System.out.println(url.toString());
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
            InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
            String encoding = uc.getContentEncoding();
            encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8"
                    // "windows-1251"
                    // "Cp1251"
                    : encoding;
            body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use Java's [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) As in `URLEncoder.encode("Børomìr", "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 2):

This is what is called [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and is what is used in URLs. There are many tools that allow you to decode it like [this one](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/). Specifically in java, it has a [URL encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)